# Add few properties of class in list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class with 8 properties declared:

```
public  class  classProduct
{
    public int iProductID { get; set; }
    public string sPName { get; set; }
    public string sPDescription { get; set; }
    public int iPTypeID { get; set; }
    public string sPPrice { get; set; }
    public string sPType { get; set; }
    public string sImagePath { get; set; }
    public string sDestinationPath { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a method in which I add 4 properties in my list like and ProductDetailsTbls is my Tbl1 and ProductTypeTbls is Tbl2.

```
public List<classProduct> GetAllProduct()
{ 
    List<classProduct> lst = new List<classProduct>();
    lst = (from c in dc.ProductDetailsTbls
             join d in dc.ProductTypeTbls
             on c.PTypeID equals d.PTypeID
             select new classProduct { sPName=c.PName, sPDescription=c.PDescription, sPPrice=c.PPrice, sPType=d.PType }).ToList();
    return lst;
}
```

But it returns all properties that I don't want.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to come out?

Comment: desired output is sPName,sPDescription,sPPrice,sPType

Comment: @RahulSingh :how to assigned explicitly.

Comment: You can create a class with only sPName,sPDescription,sPPrice,sPType properties and return that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want some properties I think you will have to introduce a new class.

My approach for this would be to define a base class with your four properties and then you can `classProduct` inherit from it.

your base-class then looks like:

```
public class baseClassProduct
{
    public string sPName { get; set; }
    public string sPDescription { get; set; }
    public string sPPrice { get; set; }
    public string sPType { get; set; }
}
```

and your classProduct:

```
public class classProduct : baseClassProduct
{
    public int iProductID { get; set; }
    public int iPTypeID { get; set; }
    public string sImagePath { get; set; }
    public string sDestinationPath { get; set; }
}
```

In your GetAllProduct-Method you can work with the baseClass and you'll get only the information you want to.

```
public List<baseClassProduct> GetAllProduct()
{ 
    List<baseClassProduct> lst = new List<baseClassProduct>();
    lst = (from c in dc.ProductDetailsTbls
             join d in dc.ProductTypeTbls
             on c.PTypeID equals d.PTypeID
             select new baseClassProduct { sPName=c.PName, sPDescription=c.PDescription, sPPrice=c.PPrice, sPType=d.PType }).ToList();
   return lst;
}
```